# Express Post Request returns 404 status

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am creating an API using express, mongoose and node.js. I am having problems with building a post request endpoint for one of my collections. I have a payment schema defined using mongoose and make the post request for that collection in my server file. I have double checked the path for the files and they are correct. I send a similar post request to the API using postman:

{
   type: "cdvdsvd"
}

This gives me an error 404. Please help

```js
//Mongoose file

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; 
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/CSapp", { useNewUrlParser: true });
module.exports = {
    mongoose
};
```

```js
//Collection Schema

var {mongoose} = require('../db/mongoose'); 

var Payments = mongoose.model('Payments', {
    type: {
        type: String, 
        default: 'Incoming'
    }, 
    Date_Entry: {
        day: Number,
        month: String,
        year: Number
    }, Due_date: {
        day: Number,
        month: String,
        year: Number
    }, 
    Amount: {
        type: Number,
    }, 
    Party: {
        type: String,
    },
    Category: {
            type: String,
    }, 
    Description: {
        type: String,
    }
}); 

module.exports = {
    Payments
};
```

```js
//Server file
const express = require('express'); 
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
const _ = require('lodash');

const {mongoose} = require('./db/mongoose'); 
const {Payments} = require('./models/payment');
const {Budgets} = require('./models/Budgets'); 

var port = 3000 || process.env; 
var app =  express();
app.use(body_parser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//POST REQUESTS
    //POST Payments
    app.post('/payments', (request, response) => {
        var payment = new Payments({
            type: request.body.type
        }); 

        payment.save().then((docs) => {
            response.send(docs);
            console.log(docs); 
        }, (e) => {
            response.status(404).send(e); 
        });
    }); 

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('Server initiated. Now listening on port: ' + port);
    }); 

    module.exports = {
        app
    };
```

Comment: If the path is correct, maybe your call to `save()` fails and responds with a 404?!

Comment: Try to log out an error before sending 404 response. You'll find out what breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save), there are two ways that you can see if the `Payment` is correctly saved or there was an error in the process.

They are:

> 1. Callbacks

To use a callback, the `save()` function must take the callback as a parameter and the callback should take two parameters, which are the `err` and the `docs`. Like this.

```
payment.save((err, docs) => {
   if (err) {
      return response.status(404).send(err);
   }
   response.send(docs);
   console.log(docs);
})
```

> 2. Promises

While using a promise we have to chain a `then()` function to the `save()` and catch the error like this.

```
    payment.save().then((docs) => {
        response.send(docs);
        console.log(docs); 
    }).catch((e) => response.status(404).send(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

- First Try `console.log(err);` to try printing your err object under an `if` block preferably.
- Then check your data object by printing it before calling `save()` function as you are using `new` keyword here.
  if this doesnt solve it pls tell what did the error & data objets contain.
- Check the mongoose docs for more clarity as akrion has mentioned.